How do you define textScaler globally in Flutter?
I'm working to make my app readable for users who have large text accessibility enabled for their device. I am aware that the Text widget has a parameter, 'textScaler' (formerly textScaleFactor), however, is it necessary to define this textScaler for every text widget?
I tried wrapping the Material App with MediaQuery and assigned the textScaler a value of 1.2 in its data, however, this removes the capability of the user from using their keyboard.
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
        textScaler: const TextScaler.linear(1.2),
      ),
      child: MaterialApp.router(...

